# Why is PEMDOS not followed in the following example

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am working through a practice math exam, and had trouble on this problem...

"Which expression below is equivalent to 4(4y-10)(y+5)/4(y-5)"

The answer was (4y-10)(y+5)(y-5). The steps to the solution start with, "Any expression divided by itself equals 1" so the problem just get simplified to
(4y-10)(y+5)(y-5) giving the answer, but I'm not following how it gets to that form.

If I start with
[starting point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Z2Kj.png)

it would simplify to
[simplified version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWSLJ.png)

But then I'm not sure how to get to (4y-10)(y+5)(y-5)

Any help or resources are greatly appreciated!

Comment: The only thing being divided here is the 4 as you have it written, the (y-5) then becomes a new multiplication

Comment: Not sure I follow, why does (y-5) become a new multiplication after dividing the 4? Thanks

Comment: According to the rules, $4(4y-10)(y+5)/4(y-5) = (4(4y-10)(y+5)/4)(y-5).$ But what is this a practice exam for? It might not help, but you might enjoy this article. https://www.nytimes.com/2019/08/06/science/math-equation-pemdas.html

Comment: A mathematician would always write this as $$\frac{4(4y-10)(y+5)}{4}(y-5)$$

Comment: It's for a pre-nursing TEAS test, that article from NYT is a good read hehe
Writing it in that format makes the problem's solution way more apparent, I appreciate it

Comment: PEMDAS (or whatever you call it) is ambiguous in cases like this (in particular with division to the left of a multiplication). Such cases should therefore be avoided as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps $4(4y-10)(y+5)/4(y-5)$ means
$$
\frac{4\;(4y-10)\;(y+5)}{4\;(y-5)}
\tag1$$
I think this is most likely.
Or perhaps it means
$$
\frac{4\;(4y-10)\;(y+5)}{4}\;(y-5)
\tag2$$
I think $(2)$ is less likely.  Why? If you really wanted this, then the original would have been written
$4(4y-10)(y+5)(y-5)/4$ by a careful mathematician.

Comment: Based on the answer to the problem, I think that (2) is the right way to write it...4s would cancel and then you'd be left with (4y-10)(y+5)(y-5) which is what the answer in the book is, thank you!

Comment: A "careful mathematician" wouldn't touch an expression like $4(4y-10)(y+5)/4(y-5)$ with a ten-foot pole. They would use proper fraction notation or parentheses to disambiguate.